# node.js - the best way to replace content in buffer

Tags: node.js, buffer

I am reading a file to buffer like:

```js
var myfile = fs.readFileSync(myfile.txt);
```

What is the proper way to replace some string to another in `myfile` buffer? I would like to keep it as buffer, because it is faster than to keep it as string.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://blog.strongloop.com/practical-examples-of-the-new-node-js-streams-api/

Comment: Related to the Node.js `Buffer.replace` feature request: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5683 (2016)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, a buffer handles raw binary data. It does not provide string-related functionnalities.

As far as I know, you must convert it to String first (`toString()` method) before searching and replacing strings inside.

If you knows the index of your searched string, you can make copy the buffer content before and after the index into a new buffer, and concatenate your replaced content.
But in this case, you'll encounter encoding problems...

The buffer doc: http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer

Comment: Well... this is kind of annoying because switching buffer to string and back takes sooo much resources especially when buffer is big. Isn't it better to chunk-read the buffer starting from position 0 and ending at buffer.length - chunk.length where chunk size would be same as size of searched string and then replace byte by byte? Wouldn't it be faster especially when string would get found and we make only replace-once?

Comment: I guess that you're using buffer because your data is streamed. In that case, I suggest you to process it part by part, and to use buffertools as user568109 mention and "make holes" as you said it wasn't problematic. But perhpas you could give more details on your case and get more accurate suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The package buffer-replace https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer-replace replaces content in a buffer like the function replace for String.

Answer (score 0):

What would happen if `abcdef` is replaced by `ghi`. It would leave a hole in the buffer, since buffers cannot be resized. The least you can do is search into Buffer for the string and create another output Buffer replacing the string (may require intermediate buffers).

JavaScript's string replace handles strings efficiently this way. If you still want to use Buffers, you can look into [buffertools](https://npmjs.org/package/buffertools). It has `indexOf` function which searches the Buffer for string. `replace` is something you would have to implement yourself.

Comment: True. But that does not concern me. It is better to leave a hole in the buffer than to rewrite it.

Comment: @FlashThunder And what if you want `ghi` to be replaced by `abcdef` ?

Comment: well, in my case, the things I would like to replace are defined by me... so I can make it as long as I need. But of course, you are right. The only way seems to be making a huge buffer and rewrite it totally. Still seems to be faster than stringifing.

Comment: @FlashThunder I doubt you will get faster results with buffer. Buffer is faster only if you have to read/write large amounts of data, like sockets dealing with binary data. Strings are better optimised for such operations. You should store your data as String instead of Buffer. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901570/buffer-vs-string-speed-why-is-string-faster.

Comment: In my case one such a buffer is > 2MB

Comment: I have used bigger strings, read files into strings to match regex. Buffer may only look like greener pasture. There is little evidence of Buffers being faster here, that you can rely on.