# Are there, currently, noticeable performance advantages in using Buffer / Uint8Array instead of plain arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I believe, nowadays, JavaScript engines such as V8 are always able to detect when an array has only numeric values in the `0-255` range and, thus, store it as an unboxed Uint8 array. As such, one could expect they're as efficient as the strongly typed counterparts. Having a single array type across your codebase is, though, much more convenient than having many.

In 2017, is there still a noticeable performance advantage in using `Buffer`/`Uint8Array`s rather than plain arrays?

Comment: How could V8 make such an optimization when it has no guarantee of what the next data type added to the Array will be? Out of curiosity, could you provide a link to where you read about that detection?

Comment: @peteb it keeps the whole array wrapped in an object that performs a lightweight type check whenever you insert something. If you're inserting something that isn't a byte, V8 unpacks the whole thing and builds an untyped array back. At least, that is how I assumed it works. I never read about it actually.

Answer (score 0):

See the below code which I used for performance testing [using this RunKit](https://runkit.com/vandivier/buffer-vs-array-performance-test). It indicates that `Buffer` is slower, which is consistent with some other historic data.

Other related data points:

1. [This jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/array-vs-object-buffer)
2. [This other jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/msgpack-arraybuffer-vs-js2/4)
3. [This older SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901570/buffer-vs-string-speed-why-is-string-faster).

   ```
   //setup
   //const iNumTests = 1000;
   const iNumTests = 1000;
   let arrResults = [];

   function randomChar() {
   var chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
   return chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
   }

   function singleTest() {
       //buffer
       const t0 = process.hrtime();
       let buf = Buffer.from(randomChar());  //recommended to initialize with .from()
       for (var i = 1; i < iNumTests; ++i) {
           buf.write(randomChar());
       }
       var sOutput = buf.toString();
       const arrBuff = process.hrtime(t0);

       //array
       const t1 = process.hrtime();
       let chars = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < iNumTests; ++i) {
           chars.push(randomChar());
       }
       var sOutput = chars.join('');
       const arrArray = process.hrtime(t1);

       //delta
       const timeBuff = arrBuff[0] * 1e9 + arrBuff[1];
       const timeArray = arrArray[0] * 1e9 + arrArray[1];
       return (timeBuff - timeArray);
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < iNumTests; i++) {
       arrResults.push(singleTest());
   }

   var sum = arrResults.reduce(function(acc, val) {
     return acc + val;
   }, 0);

   console.log(sum/iNumTests);         // average difference. I got 146929.598 which means timeBuff is larger on average.
   ```